# No url found for submodule path 'XXXXXXX' in .gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have problem while using git in one of the platform I'm using,
it shows this error while the url is already define in .git/config file:

**Note**:if I use master branch no error, but if I use none branch I get the error. even if the code is identical

```
 [core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://bitbucket.XXXXX.com/project.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "none"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/none
```

if I try to do "git submodule add URL" === error alreedy exist.

Comment: The URLs listed in `.git/config` are for the remotes for *this repository*. The missing URL for a submodule is found, or rather, not found, in a `.gitmodules` file. The fact that it's not missing in other branches, but is missing in branch `none`, indicates that the submodule appears specifically in the commit in branch `none` that you're looking at, and the URL is missing in the `.gitmodules` file in that same commit.

Comment: I didnt understand how i fix it.. the code shown from none branch... even if I edit the file the git add not recognize that the file is edited

Comment: should I make file called .gitmodules?? then add what??

Comment: Generally you'd use `git submodule add` but in this case it sounds like the submodule is already "half added". I'm not sure what the formally correct way is for doing this; I'd just create the `.gitmodules` entry manually myself, but that's a little tricky.

Comment: Remember that a submodule is a **reference to** *a different repository*. The reference is stored as a pair of items: a *gitlink* (one per submodule, stored in each commit) and information in a text file named `.gitmodules` (one file for all submodules, also stored in each commit).